# How to compare single property from 2 array using c# execution time should be minimum

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays variables and values like below

```
arraydata1 =

[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "bbb"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "ccc"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "aaa"
  }
]
```

and

```
arraydata2 =

[
  {
    "id": "111",
    "tablename": "aaa"
  },
  {
    "id": "222",
    "tablename": "bbb"
  }
]
```

I want to compare `arraydata1.name == arraydata2.tablename` and if matching then form new array from arraydata1 .

output is -

```
[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "aaa"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "bbb"
      },
    {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "aaa"
   }
    ]
```

I have more than 2000+ records to compare in `arraydata1` how to reduce time as well. I can use normal foreach but it will take too much time to compare.

I was doing inside logic app using 2 foreach so it is taking time. so i thought better to use c# code.

Comment: Does the order matter? If there are multiple elements in arraydata1 with the same name, would you expect multiple elements in the output? Are there ever multiple elements in arraydata2 with the same tablename? I strongly suspect that a LINQ join would do this trivially, but we really need to know more first.

Comment: please post the problematic code. How do you compare? and How did you loop?

Comment: Have you tried to create a dictionary where key is a `name` and value is an item from array?

Comment: arraydata2.tablename is unique but arraydata1.name could come multiple times.

Comment: and do you want to keep the duplicate `name`s? or do you need only the first, or last or... ?

Comment: Put the keys from `array2` into a `HashSet<string>`. Use a `Where` on `array1` where the `HashSet` `Contain`s the key. This will work **assuming** you want to keep duplicates from `array1`.

Comment: "but it will take too much time to compare" how long does it take on your machine? With over 2300 entries in both arrays I get a runtime of 2 loops around 120 msec. Is this already too long ?

Comment: I'm doing compare into logic app using 2 foreach that why taking time...so though to do it using c# code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Linq solution could look like this:

```
var tableNameKeys = arraydata2.Select(t => t.tablename).ToHashSet();
var resultArray = arraydata1.Where(x => tableNameKeys.Contains(x.name)).ToArray();
```

The advantage of this approach is that [HashSet.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

> ... is an O(1) operation.

Result:

[image]